# Automatically add licenses headers

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, gulp

Is there a project that automatically adds licenses headers to web projects (Javascript, HTML, CSS, other files) ?
For example, a simple Grunt task with a configuration like:

```
licenses: {
  options: {
    type: "MIT"
  },
  default: {
    src: [ "**/*.{js,html,css}" ]
  }
}
```

The task would add a license header if the file doesn't have one or replace it otherwise.

If such a project doesn't exist, I will consider creating a Grunt task (or Gulp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use gulp-license. https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-license